# CSSGrid repeating, dynamic, horizontal div elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am pretty new on CSS/Html/JS and want to create a series of Boxes (loaded from a json file) and display them horizontally. Something like This:

[image]

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
<style> 
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.Product {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    background-color: rgb(2, 121, 61);
    padding: 10px;
}

</style>
<div class"Wrapper">
    <div class="Product">
        <div>Pos: </div><div id="pos">test1</div>
        <div>Artikel: </div><div id="article">test2</div>
        <div>Bezeichnung: </div><div id="name">test3</div>
        <div>Menge: </div><div id="stock">test4</div>
        <div>Einheit:</div><div id="einheit">test5</div>
        <div>Lagerplatz:</div><div id="shelf">test6</div>
        <div>Intern:</div><div id="barcode">test7</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Product">
        <div>Pos: </div><div id="pos">test1</div>
        <div>Artikel: </div><div id="article">test2</div>
        <div>Bezeichnung: </div><div id="name">test3</div>
        <div>Menge: </div><div id="stock">test4</div>
        <div>Einheit:</div><div id="einheit">test5</div>
        <div>Lagerplatz:</div><div id="shelf">test6</div>
        <div>Intern:</div><div id="barcode">test7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the result looks like this:

[image: css_result]

As you can see the divs are not horizontal and the width fills the screen. I want the boxes to be horizontally aligned and not to stop at the screen end. If I could put the whole element into a horizontal scroll view I would be even happier. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `auto` is 100%..you need to use an inline-grid on the product divs

Comment: class=wrapper ... fix the tyo error and it will be fine

Comment: thanks inline-grid did the trick. with this I don't even need the .wrapper style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your product class use inline-grid...

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.Product {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    background-color: rgb(2, 121, 61);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class"Wrapper">
    <div class="Product">
        <div>Pos: </div><div id="pos">test1</div>
        <div>Artikel: </div><div id="article">test2</div>
        <div>Bezeichnung: </div><div id="name">test3</div>
        <div>Menge: </div><div id="stock">test4</div>
        <div>Einheit:</div><div id="einheit">test5</div>
        <div>Lagerplatz:</div><div id="shelf">test6</div>
        <div>Intern:</div><div id="barcode">test7</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Product">
        <div>Pos: </div><div id="pos">test1</div>
        <div>Artikel: </div><div id="article">test2</div>
        <div>Bezeichnung: </div><div id="name">test3</div>
        <div>Menge: </div><div id="stock">test4</div>
        <div>Einheit:</div><div id="einheit">test5</div>
        <div>Lagerplatz:</div><div id="shelf">test6</div>
        <div>Intern:</div><div id="barcode">test7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at least fix the code error or remove it ... and warn him about the use of id

Answer (score 0):

You specify the `wrapper` class wrong. You should put `wrapper` not `Wrapper` in the main div `class`. If you want a space between columns you can use `grid-column-gap: 20px;`